# Django Contact Form

Tags: python, django, forms, contacts

i created a contact form using django that sends name, email and message. The form goes through successfully with the name, subject attach however only a portion of the message arrives to gmail instead of the whole message. how can i get the full message to show you on the gmail account?

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## Forms

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Contact

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'message',)
```

## views

```
def contact(request):
mapbox_access_token = 'pk.my_mapbox_access_token'
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ContactForm()
else:
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sender_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        emailFrom = form.cleaned_data['email']
        message = "{0} has sent you a new message:\n\n{1}".format(sender_name, form.cleaned_data['message'])


        form.save()
        try:
            send_mail('New Enquiry', message, emailFrom, ['va.glazing@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False, )
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
        return redirect('success')

return render(request, "contact.html",{'form': form})
#settings

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****.***.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Here are the images of the result i get once the email goes through.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/31SBv.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MGgc.png

Comment: You're not showing us how you're sending the email. Where's that code? Note: Don't add these widgets to your form, they're redundant and why do have these empty attributes anyway?

Comment: thanks for the comment, i have fix the code as it is in the picture above. however i still get the same error. i can not get the full message on my email when i send it.

Comment: Look at the order of arguments for [send_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#send-mail). Your order is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/):

```
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

As you can see, your are writing message and email in wrong place. Switching place should solve the problem.

`name` will be your subject, `email` will be the from part and `message` the message content.

Comment: thank you, i edit the view code as in the picture above. now the issue is that im not able to show the emailFrom on my gmail account. how can i fix my code so im able to see the from and to emails?

Comment: @MarcoEHurtado you can't send `emailFrom` directly in send_mail, it is a Form object. Use `form.cleaned_data['message']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `'subject': forms.TextInput(attrs={'': ''})` to your `widgets` dict, and similarly to your form. They seem to be colliding.